# the screen on elementary on looks green Help

Tags: bugs, error

Can anyone help me . I already installed Elementary OS but the screen is totally green. I tried to reinstall Nvidia drivers, configure manually the gamma but I didn't get a change. I am a newbie and I don't know to fixed.
I have a Nvidia rtx 3050 and its connected by hdmi